# Let $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $\ t \mapsto nt(1-t)^n$. Show $M_n := \sup\{ f_n(t) \mid t \in [0,1]\} = (\frac n {n+1})^{n+1}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $\ t \mapsto nt(1-t)^n$.
>
> Show $M_n := \sup\{ f_n(t) \mid t \in [0,1]\} = (\frac n {n+1})^{n+1}$.

I've already proved that $\{f_n\}$ is pointwise convergent sequence with limit function $t \mapsto 0$.

However, I'm having trouble proving the above statement and that $M_n \rightarrow e^{-1}$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Also I know $(1+\frac x n)^n, n = 1,2, \ldots$ has limit $e^{x}$, so if I can prove the statement in question, I have $(\frac n {n+1})^{n+1} = (1 +\frac {-1} {n+1})^{n+1}$ which converge to $e^{-1}$ right ?

Comment: Did you do an array of variation of the function?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. I proved pointwise convergent by proving $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n z^n = 0$ for $|z| < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. If you know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$, then you obtain $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} M_n = e^{-1}$ in the way you want.

To verify the given value of $M_n$, note that (for $n > 0$)

- $f_n(0) = f_n(1) = 0$,
- $f_n(t) > 0$ for $0 < t < 1$, and
- $f_n$ is differentiable.

So $f_n$ attains its maximum value in a critical point in $(0,1)$, that means you need to find $t_c \in (0,1)$ with $f_n'(t_c) = 0$. Hence, start by computing $f_n'(t)$. Then find its zeros (there's only one in $(0,1)$) and compute $f_n(t_c)$.

Comment: You justify this by $[0,1]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, so supremum of $f$ on $[0,1]$ must occur at a point $c \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $[0,1]$ is compact and $f_n$ continuous, the supremum is actually a maximum. And since (for $n > 0$) it cannot be attained in one of the endpoints, it must be attained in a critical point in $(0,1)$.

Comment: I get $f_n^{'}(t) = n(1-t)^n + n^2t(1-t)^{n-1} = 0$ imply $n(1-t)^{n-1} ((1-t)+nt) = 0$. I cannot get it into the proper form.

Comment: We assume $n > 0$, and are only interested in zeros in $(0,1)$. So two of the factors are never $0$. Therefore $t_c$ must be the zero of the third. What is $t_c$, and what is hence $f_n(t_c)$?

Comment: But $(1-t)+nt=0 \iff -t + nt = -1 \iff t(-1+n) = -1 \iff t = \frac {-1} {-1+n}$. Thus we get a negative number for $t$ as the only solution.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked your sign error, sorry. You have a sign error in your computation of the derivative. After fixing that, it all works out neatly.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your great support. I've sorted it out all correctly now.